How to set the register from the data from memory using the CMOVG instruction?
The problem is inside the Graphic subroutine at row 236. (4th, 13th and 16th row in sublabel .writePixel).
In this subroutine I browse the graphic pixel from 280 to 487 column and 368 to 385 row. (pixel area is 16x8).
If I find the black pixel then I write the pixel from suitable area of vertical stripes using the cmovg instruction and interrupt int 10h with BIOS function 0Ch.
I have problem with operands of cmovg instruction. I want to copy value from data memory (global variable barvy_kontrola) to AX register (AH must be 0Ch and AL must be value of graphic pixel).
The program crashes in the first use of cmovg instruction.
The piece of code:
pusha
mov si, text_b
call print_string_end2
popa

is tester block (write the text at 23 row and 35 column of text area (80 x 25))
The code is below:
use16
org 0100h


; Return to main entry
Main:

; Set video position and clear the screen automatically
mov ah, 00h     ;Invoked with: AH = 00h
mov al, 03h     ;text video mode (CGA 80 x 25)
int 10h


; background draw
mov ah, 09h
mov al, 20h         ; ASCII char 20h [32(decimal)] is space 
xor bh, bh      ; set display page 0
mov bl, 1eh     ; background of text is blue, foreground is yellow
mov cx, 2000        ; 2000 x copy of space
int 10h
    

; set cursor position
mov ah, 02h     
mov dx, 0624h       ; dh = 06h - dl = 24h (row - column)
int 10h


mov si, text_a
call print_string


; set cursor position
add dh, 02h     ; rows = rows + 2
sub dl, 0fh     ; column = column - 15
push dx         ; column index saved
mov ah, 02h
int 10h

mov si, text_b
call print_string

; set cursor position
pop dx      ; load index of column
add dh, 01h     ; rows = rows + 1

mov ah, 02h
int 10h

push dx     ; save cursor of column to next start writing text

mov si, text_c
call print_string

; set cursor position
pop dx      ; load index of column
add dh, 02h     ; rows = rows + 2
mov ah, 02h
int 10h

push dx     ; save cursor of column to next start writing text

mov si, text_d
call print_string

; set cursor position
pop dx      ; load index of column
add dh, 02h     ; rows = rows + 2
add dl, 06h ; columns = columns + 6
mov ah, 02h
int 10h

mov si, text_e
call print_string

;Save current Video mode (get Video mode and save it)
mov ah, 0fh
int 10h         ; returns: current mode in al
push ax         ; save


; Read next character to select the choice
mov ah, 01h
int 21h

cmp al, 31h         ; 31h is 49 in decimal "1"
jz short choice_1
cmp al, 32h     ; 32h is 50 in decimal "2"
jz short choice_2


; other choice exit the program with next code


; wait for key press to exit program
Exit:
mov ah, 07h     
int 21h
ret

; choices from the menu
choice_1:       ; horizontal color stripes
xor ah, ah      ; set graphic mode with resolution (640 x 480)
mov al, 12h
int 10h 

;/////////
xor bl, bl          ; index pro proch?zen? barev
mov si, barvy
mov ah, 0ch     ; Write pixel
mov al, byte [si]
xor cx, cx
xor dx, dx

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
YBack:
int 10h
inc cx
cmp cx, 640
jb short YBack
xor cx, cx
inc dx

pusha           ; ulo?en? registr? do z?sobn?ku
mov ax, dx
xor dx, dx
mov bx, 120
div bx
or dx, dx
popa
jnz short YBack
inc bl
cmp bl, 4
je text_continue
inc si
mov al, byte [si]
jmp short YBack
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;



choice_2:       ; vertical color stripes
xor ah, ah      ; set graphic mode with resolution (640 x 480)
mov al, 12h
int 10h 

;/////////
xor bl, bl      ; index pro procházení barev
mov si, barvy
mov ah, 0ch     ; write pixel
mov al, byte [si]
xor cx, cx
xor dx, dx
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
XBack:          
int 10h
inc dx
cmp dx, 480
jb short XBack
xor dx, dx
inc cx

pusha           ; uložení registrů do zásobníku
mov ax, cx
mov bx, 160
div bx
or dx, dx
popa
jnz short XBack
inc bl
cmp bl, 4
je short text_continue_2
inc si
mov al, byte [si]
jmp short XBack
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


print_string_end2:  
mov ah, 02h     ; Set cursor
mov dh, 23      ; 23. ??dek
mov dl, 35      ; 35. sloupec
int 10h
mov ah, 02h
.print_char_eE:
mov dl, [si]
inc si
or dl, dl
jz short .DoneP
int 21h
jmp short .print_char_eE
.DoneP:
ret

text_continue_2:    ; vykreslení textu "Pres any key to continue" a překreslení pixelů

mov si, text_f
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; Write text

call print_string_end2

call Graphic


pop ax          ; restore video mode
int 10h

jmp Exit        ; nastavit skok do Main



;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Graphic:
mov cx, 280     ; počáteční sloupec (starting row) (left upper corner if string area)
mov dx, 368     ; počáteční řádek (starting column)+

.ZBack:
mov ah, 0dh     ; BIOS funkce čtení pixelu
int 10h
cmp al, 00h
jz short .writePixel
.ContinueZBack:
inc cx
cmp cx, 488
jb short .ZBack
mov cx, 280
inc dx
cmp dx, 386
jb short .ZBack
jmp short .DoneX

.writePixel:
mov di, barvy_kontrola
mov ax, 0c02h       ; pro pojištění kdyby nedopadla žádná podmínka (defaultní nastavení pixelu)
cmp cx, 479
cmovg ax, [di] ;[barvy_kontrola]

pusha
mov si, text_b
call print_string_end2
popa

add di, 02h
cmp cx, 319
cmovg ax, [di]
add di, 02h
cmp cx, 159
cmovg ax, [di]
int 10h         ; BIOS funkce pro zápis pixelu
jmp short .ContinueZBack

.DoneX:
ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


text_continue:      ; print text "Pres any key to continue"
pop ax          ; restore video mode
int 10h
mov si, text_f
call print_string_end
jmp Exit        ; místo Exit nastavit do Main



print_string:
mov ah, 09h
mov bl, 1eh         ; background is blue, foreground is yellow
mov cx, 01h

.print_char:
lodsb
or al, al
jz short .done
int 10h

push ax
mov ah, 02h     ; Bios function to set cursor position
inc dl          ; move cursor
int 10h
pop ax
jmp short .print_char

.done:
ret

print_string_end:   
mov ah, 02h     ; Set cursor
mov dh, 23      ; 23. ??dek
mov dl, 35      ; 35. sloupec
int 10h

.print_string_e:
mov ah, 02h
.print_char_e:
mov dl, [si]
inc si
or dl, dl
jz short .Continue
int 21h
jmp short .print_char_e

.Continue:
mov si, barvy
lea di, [barvy + 3]
xor bl, bl

;Read pixel and write new pixel

.ContinueColor:
mov dx, 368     ; row
mov cx, 280
mov ah, 0dh     ; function of read graphic pixel

.Gback:
int 10h
cmp al, [si]        ; [si]  <= mov si, barvy        
jnz short .GbackRow
push ax
mov ah, 0ch
mov al, [di]        ; [di] <= lea di, [barvy + 3]
int 10h
pop ax
jmp short .GbackRow

.GbackRow:
inc cx
cmp cx, 488
jb short .Gback
mov cx, 280     ; start column
inc dx
cmp dx, 386
jb short .Gback


lea si, [barvy + 4]
mov di, barvy
inc bl
cmp bl, 02h
jb short .ContinueColor
ret

; Exit program
Return:
ret

text_a: db "MENU", 00h
text_b: db "1 - HORIZONTAL STRIPES", 00h
text_c: db "2 - VERTICAL STRIPES", 00h
text_d: db "Q - QUIT", 00h
text_e: db "ENTER CHOICE:", 00h

text_f: db "Press any key to continue", 00h
barvy: db 00h, 05h, 0eh, 01h, 0fh       ; color Black, Magenta, Yellow, Dark blue; White
barvy_kontrola: db 0ch, 01h, 0ch, 0eh, 0ch, 05h

I would like to redraw the background of the text area in Graphic mode 12h using the subroutine Graphic (below of the code). The text area is "1 - HORIZONTAL STRIPESnue" to suitable graphic pixel of graphic vertical stripes.
I use FASM assembler.

What do you mean it crashes? What environment do you use? What processor?

That means the program froze and stop. Enviroment is emulator DOSBox (version v0 .74-3) and operating system is "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional" (version is "6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Sestavení 7601"). Type of system is "x64-based PC". Processor is "Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7".

dosbox does not support cmov.  Use simple conditional jumps instead.


The program crash in the first using of cmovg instruction.

First make sure that you have access to this particular instruction. You can find out about its availability through inspecting the outcome from the cpuid instruction:
mov  eax, 1
cpuid            ; -> EAX EBX ECX EDX
bt   edx, 15
jnc  NotSupported

It would be safe to use cmovg (and friends) if the carry flag was set here.
And if cmovg does work, then you have an important error in the barvy_kontrola array.

barvy_kontrola: db 0ch, 01h, 0ch, 0eh, 0ch, 05h


Since x86 is a little-endian architecture, loading AX from this array is going to put the BIOS function number in the AL register instead of in the AH register where it belongs. The color goes in AL though.
You can write:
barvy_kontrola: dw 0C01h, 0C0Eh, 0C05h

or
barvy_kontrola: db 01h, 0Ch, 0Eh, 0Ch, 05h, 0Ch


thank your for your help.
I try it and result is jump to label NotSupported.
Before mov instruction I save the gpr registers to stack
pusha
